# Files from which vmstat information come from

Tags: superuser

I would very much like to know the names and locations of the files from which `vmstat` command information comes from in Linux OS.

Comment: then run it with strace and grep for open.

Comment: `man vmstat` has a section called `FILES` that lists which files it uses.

Comment: Not a programming specific question - try [unix.se] or [su].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User space tools reporting statistics likely get them from the kernel through procfs/sysfs file systems.
As most of them are open sources, it is easy to read the source code. For example, a way to get the package name it comes from is to display the version:

```
$ vmstat --version
vmstat from procps-ng 3.3.16
```

From the preceding, you know that you can grab the source code from [procps-ng](https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps) package.

And as said in the comments by [Stark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1216776/stark), you can spy the execution of `vmstat` with `strace` tool and you will see which files are opened to get the information:

```
$ strace vmstat
[...]
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/meminfo", O_RDONLY) = 3
[...]
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/stat", O_RDONLY) = 4
[...]
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/vmstat", O_RDONLY) = 5
[...]
```